# Need to create a string token dynamically base on which method is calling it

Tags: asp.net

This is a minimal code.

I have the string Str which is used by various methods. I want to in getId method be able to do 2 things

1. Assign class="PDP" to it and
2. Give it a value3

So the final string looks like

`<tr class='PDP' id='{2}'> <td {0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>`

But please note that I will need different values for class in different methods so some Str will have PDP, another will have PTM etc. Is there a clean way to achieve this .

```
private const string Str = "<tr><td >{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>";

public static string getId()
{
  string  field=string.Format(str, value1,value2, found=true? value3:"");
}
```

Comment: I have the string Str which is used by various methods. I want to in getId method be able to do 2 things

 1. Assign class="PDP" to it
 2. Give it a value3

So the final string looks like 
    <tr class='PDP' id='{2}'> <td {0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>

But please note that I will need different values for class in different methods so some Str will have PDP, another will have PTM etc. Is there a clean way to achieve this .

private const string Str = "<tr><td >{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>";

public static string getId()
{
  string  field=string.Format(str, value1,value2, found=true? value3:"");
}

Answer (score 0):

```
private const string Str = "<tr {0} {1}><td >{2}</td><td>{3}</td></tr>";

public static string getId(string cssClass, string id)
{
  return string.Format(str, 
         (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cssClass))?string.Format("class='{0}'", cssClass):"",
         (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))? string.Format("id='{0}'",id):"",
         value1,value2, );
}
```

Comment: Can't i use something like....
Str = "<tr ##class## {1}><td >{2}</td><td>{3}</td></tr>";

And assign some value to ##class## in different methods. Aslo please not that the value for class is hardcoded but str is generated dynamically at runtime

Comment: So what I want is that only assign a class="PDP" or class="PTM" only if it is needed and the rest of the methods have str set with no class definition in the <tr>

Comment: You could always just a string.Replace() on a section, if that's what you want.  Personally I think this is cleaner.

Comment: And note that you can just pass `null` to this method and there will no class in the output.

Comment: okay. But when i do a {0} in Str all places that I call I have to assign a value or a null.